# Why is "State" spelt with a capital, but "federal" is not?

Tags: capitalization

They both mean the same noun, yet one is spelt with a capital?

Comment: http://www.lawprose.org/lawprose-lesson-217-when-do-you-capitalize-federal-and-state/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should ‘state’ be capitalised?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/279813/when-should-state-be-capitalised)

Comment: Can you give us some examples??

Comment: "These problems arise from the basic discontinuity between federal and State systems".

Comment: "The relationship between the judicial branch of government and other
branches is an important policy consideration in allocating original jurisdiction between state and federal courts" - no capitalisation here

Comment: That first example is either due to an error on the part of the writer or the use of capitalized "State" to imply a specific state (the one presumably under discussion).

Comment: "Section 77 of the Constitution permits the investment of State courts with
federal jurisdiction, but such jurisdiction cannot be conferred on a body which
is not a court" - another example by same author

Comment: "which provides for the vesting of federal jurisdiction in the courts of the States as well as federal courts" - similar to above

Comment: Whether to capitalize those words is a matter of the publisher's style. For example, the Associated Press doesn't capitalize either, but the Government Publishing Office capitalizes both.

Comment: If you are quoting the Constitution, you should realize that they used more capital letters back in 1789 than is customary today.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there are specific rules in place, such as for particular documents or particular prescribed styles, "state" follows the same rules as any other word, capitalised when it's a proper noun or part of a proper name.

If you look at the Wikipedia article titled United Nations General Assembly Resolution you'll see that it lists:

> Resolution 273: Admits the State of Israel to membership in the United
>   Nations.

"State of Israel" being a proper name, so capitalised by Wikipedia.

However:

> Resolution 62/149: ... Calls on states which have abolished the death
>   penalty not to reintroduce it.
>   [UN GA Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_General_Assembly_resolution)

The Wikipedia article has not capitalised "states" because it's not a proper noun here.

> Resolution 67/19: Recognizing the State of Palestine as a non-member
>   observer state.

Wikipedia has capitalised "state" in "State of Palestine" because it's a proper name, but not observer "state".

However if you look in the UN resolution:

> ...to resolve the status of Jerusalem as the capital of two States.
>   [UN GA Resolution_67/19](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_General_Assembly_resolution_67/19)

Here you'll see that "States" is not part of a name, yet capitalised anyway.

Similarly:

> Noting that, in the judgment of the Security Council, Israel is a
>   peace-loving State and is able and willing to carry out the
>   obligations contained in the Charter,
>   [GA Resolution 273](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_General_Assembly_Resolution_273)

The UN Resolution document has capitalised "state" even if it's not a proper noun, because this is their style on official documents.

The same discrepancy is seen all over the place with all sorts of words. Governments, councils or any organisation will have their own rules and style.

Another common example is "act" as in legislative act.

> 3. (Law) (capital when part of a name) the formally codified result of deliberation by a legislative body;
>      [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/act)

Here Collins Dictionary is telling us to capitalise "act" when it's part of a name. You'll see some variation in this word's capitalisation when not part of a name.

I've seen it capitalised in Wikipedia and BrE news media articles.

So basically whether certain words are capitalised when not proper names depends entirely on what rules are being followed by a particular government, organisation etc.