# Why is 'Parliament' spelt without a capital sometimes?

Tags: capitalization

e.g. "To provide an accurate, substantially verbatim account of the proceedings of the **parliament** and its committees..."

https://www.aph.gov.au/Parliamentary_Business/Hansard/Search?q=&expand=true&drvH=0&drt=2&pnu=43&pnuH=43&pi=0&pv=&chi=2&coi=0

Comment: It's only spelled with a capital if it's a title (proper noun or name) or it's the first word in a sentence..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should ‘state’ be capitalised?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/279813/when-should-state-be-capitalised)

Answer (score 1):

[Parliament](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parliament) can refer to any legislative government body.  Its [origin](https://www.etymonline.com/word/parliament#etymonline_v_7228) is in an assembly gathered to talk.

> c. 1300, "consultation; formal conference, assembly," from Old French parlement (11c.), originally "a speaking, talk," from parler "to speak" (see parley (n.)); spelling altered c. 1400 to conform with Medieval Latin parliamentum.
>   Anglo-Latin parliamentum is attested from early 13c. Specific sense "representative assembly of England or Ireland" emerged by mid-14c. from general meaning "a conference of the secular and/or ecclesiastical aristocracy summoned by a monarch."

Typically when referring to the English House of Commons, it is capitalized as a proper noun.  When referring to an assembly in general, it is not since it does not refer to a specific proper noun.

Other interesting uses:  The collective noun ([term of venery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_terms_of_venery,_by_animal#P)) for owls is a *parliament of owls*.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks for the edit.  Missed that one . . .